# Why ssh doesn't find identity file while ssh-copy-id does?

Tags: ssh

After renaming identity files `id_ed2519_2(.pub)` to `id_ed2519(.pub)`, 
`ssh-copy-id` can connect to remoteserver using file `id_ed25519` (it asks for passphrase), while `ssh` can't, unless I add an identity file option (it asks for passphrase)  :

```
$ ssh-copy-id -n remoteserver  
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
Enter passphrase for key '/home/helloworld/.ssh/id_ed25519': 

/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: WARNING: All keys were skipped because they already exist on the remote system.

$ ssh remoteserver 
no such identity: /home/helloworld/.ssh/id_ed25519_2: No such file or directory
Permission denied (publickey).
$ ssh remoteserver -i ./ssh/id_ed25519 
Enter passphrase for key 'id_ed25519':
```

How is that possible that `ssh-copy-id` happens to find the identity files id_ed25519 without IdentityFile option, while `ssh` continues to ask for non existing file id_ed25519_2 (even after rebooting server and client) ?

Obviously there must be some configuration file saying to ssh to look for id_ed25519_2. It is not in `authorized_keys`.

Comment: Check your ssh config files.

Comment: It was in `.ssh/config`. Don't know how I managed not to look there :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ssh-copy-id is a helper script, that unless otherwise restricted (with the `-i <identity_file>` option), actively looks for all `~/.ssh/*.pub`  public key files.

Without a similar `-i <identity_file>` option `ssh` on the other hand only looks for the default `~/.ssh/id_dsa`, `~/.ssh/id_ecdsa`, `~/.ssh/id_ed25519` and `~/.ssh/id_rsa` files.
If ssh looks for other files, that is because it is configured to do so in for instance a `~/.ssh/config`  file.